# Why does the background only show when the other player picks a spot?

Tags: eclipse, sockets, icons, jpanel, readline

I am making a Connect 4 game for two players over LAN using sockets. When the server player (player one) makes a choice, he does not see his own selection, only the other player does. When the other player makes a choice, player 1 sees his own FIRST selection and the users first selection. In essence, the player does not see his current selection until his next turn. When I replace the setIcon portion with a System.out.println, it does print the line meaning that the code is reached.

Why is this and how can i fix it? If I take out the code "yourWait();", it seems to work but the user wont read for the other players choice. Thank you for any help!

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class GameBoard extends JPanel implements ActionListener
    {
        JLabel title;
        boolean isHost;

        public Button[] columnpieces = new Button[7];
        int piecesInColumn[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        JLabel[][] pieces = new JLabel[7][6];
        int colorOfPiece = 0;

        final JLabel GRID = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("GRID.gif"));
        final ImageIcon RED = new ImageIcon("RED.jpg");
        final ImageIcon BLACK = new ImageIcon("BLACK.jpg");

        JPanel one, two;

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        BufferedReader reader;
        PrintWriter writer;

        public GameBoard()
        {
            super();
            setBounds(0,0,1000, 700);
            setBackground(Color.yellow);
            setLayout(null);

            title = new JLabel("Connect 4");
            title.setBounds(0,5, 1000, 90);
            title.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 100));
            title.setForeground(Color.blue);
            title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(title);

            GRID.setBounds(200, 150, 600, 500);
            add(GRID);

            for (int a = 0; a < columnpieces.length; a ++)
            {
                columnpieces[a] = new Button("Place");
                columnpieces[a].addActionListener(this);
                columnpieces[a].setBounds(209 + 84 * a, 100, 70, 50);
                columnpieces[a].setBackground(Color.white);
                columnpieces[a].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
                add(columnpieces[a]);

                for (int b = 0; b < pieces[0].length; b ++)
                {
                    pieces[a][b] = new JLabel();
                    pieces[a][b].setBounds(208 + 83 * a,555 - 77 *b, 75,75);
                    add(pieces[a][b]);
                }
            }
        }

        public void setHost(String name) throws IOException
        {
            isHost = true;
            try {
                System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                serverSocket=new ServerSocket(706);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.err.println("Accept failed.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            try {
                writer=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }     
           yourTurn();
        }

        public void setClient(String name) throws IOException
        {
            isHost = false;
                try {
                    clientSocket=new Socket(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host address.", "192.168.1.137"),706);
                    writer=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
                    reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    System.err.println("Don't know about host.");
                    System.exit(1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection");
                    System.exit(1);
            }
            yourWait();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if (e.getSource() == columnpieces[0])
                updateFromClick(0);
            if (e.getSource() == columnpieces[1])
                updateFromClick(1);
            if (e.getSource() == columnpieces[2])
                updateFromClick(2);
            if (e.getSource() == columnpieces[3])
                updateFromClick(3);
            if (e.getSource() == columnpieces[4])
                updateFromClick(4);
            if (e.getSource() == columnpieces[5])
                updateFromClick(5);
            if (e.getSource() == columnpieces[6])
                updateFromClick(6);
        }

        void setButtonEnables(boolean enabled)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < columnpieces.length; a ++)
            {
                if(piecesInColumn[a] == 6 || !enabled)
                    columnpieces[a].setEnabled(false);
                else
                    columnpieces[a].setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        private void addPiece(int column)
        {
            int b = piecesInColumn[column];

            if(colorOfPiece % 2 == 0)
                pieces[column][b].setIcon(BLACK);
            else if (colorOfPiece % 2 == 1)
                pieces[column][b].setIcon(RED);
        }

        private void updateFromClick(int column)
        {
            addPiece(column);
            colorOfPiece +=1;
            piecesInColumn[column] +=1;
            writer.println(column);
            yourWait();
        }

        private void updateFromRecieved(int column)
        {
            addPiece(column);
            colorOfPiece +=1;
            piecesInColumn[column] +=1;
            yourTurn();
        }

        public void yourTurn()
        {
                setButtonEnables(true);
        }

        public void yourWait()
        {
                setButtonEnables(false);
                try {
                    updateFromRecieved(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.err.println("Message is not Integer.");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Message can not be read.");
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are blocking on the UI thread.

You end up calling this:

```
updateFromRecieved(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
```

in response to your click.  The problem with this is the the UI cannot repaint your screen until the `reader.readLine()` completes.  And this is, obviously, not until the opponent sends his move.

To fix this, you should consider utilizing threading to keep network code off the UI thread.  It is almost never a good idea.